# i get alway an exception INDEX OUT OF RANGE at mat[i][j] = matrix[i+1][j+1]

Tags: arrays, swift

Why am I getting index out of range in `mat[i][j] = matrix[i+1][j+1]`?

On the functions below I'm trying to count the determiner of a matrix.

Function `eraze` is to erase one line and one column so when I am filling the new matrix (array). Exception shows 'index out of range'.

```
func det2(matrix :[[Int]] ) -> Int {
    var p : Int

    p = matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]

    return p
}

func det(matrix :[[Int]] , fo : Int ) -> Int {
    var p2 : Int = 0
    if (fo == 2) {
        p2 = det2(matrix: matrix)

    } else {
        for j in 0..<fo {
            p2 = matrix[j][0] * det(matrix: eraze(matrix: matrix, nb: j, dim: fo), fo: fo-1)            
        }
    }  

    return p2
}

func eraze(matrix : [[Int]] , nb: Int , dim : Int) -> [[Int]] {
    var mat = [[Int]]()

    for i in 0..<dim-1 {
        for j in 0..<dim-1 {
            if (i == nb )  || (i>nb) {
                mat[i][j] = matrix[i+1][j+1]
            } else if (i<nb) {
                mat[i][j] = matrix[i][j+1]
            }
        }                                               
    }

    return mat
}
```

Comment: There is exactly one reason for an *index out of range* error, and that is that you're running off the end of the array/collection/list or whatever. Use the debugger to step through your code to find the exact line that is causing the issue, and then you can examine the values of the indexes to find out where you made the mistake in your logic. We can't do that for you.

Comment: Thank's  when i use the function  it return my to the body of function to a line where i don"t use any dimension of my array tht's why im confused

Comment: The debugger should tell you exactly where the issue is happening if you single step through the code. We don't have your data, we don't have the rest of your code, and we can't debug your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that in `eraze()`, you aren't initializing `mat`.  In Swift you can't index into an empty array.

Replace:

```
var mat = [[Int]]()
```

with:

```
var mat = [[Int]](repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: dim - 1), count: dim - 1)
```

---

With that change, your code no longer crashes, but it produces incorrect results.

You forgot to sum up the values of the expansion and when you do that you need to alternate the `sign` of the values:

```
func det(matrix :[[Int]] , fo : Int ) -> Int {
    func sign(_ n: Int) -> Int {
        return n % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1
    }

    var p2 : Int = 0
    if (fo == 2) {
        p2 = det2(matrix: matrix)

    } else {
        for j in 0..<fo {
            p2 += (sign(j) * matrix[j][0] * det(matrix: eraze(matrix: matrix, nb: j, dim: fo), fo: fo-1))
        }
    }

    return p2
}
```

---

**Test**

```
det(matrix: [[1, 4, 7, 3, -6], [2, 5, 8, 4, -3], [3, 6, 10, -5, 14], [1, -2, 3, 4, 5], [6, -5, 4, -3, 2]], fo: 5)
```

> ```
> 13090
> ```

which agrees with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%20of%20%5B%5B1,%204,%207,%203,%20-6%5D,%20%5B2,%205,%208,%204,%20-3%5D,%20%5B3,%206,%2010,%20-5,%2014%5D,%20%5B1,%20-2,%203,%204,%205%5D,%20%5B6,%20-5,%204,%20-3,%202%5D%5D)

Comment: THANKS YOUU ! Resolve it .. Yeah i did sign with the use of power